# Data em português retornando em inglês

Tags: php, apache, datetime, data, linux

Estou usando esse código para retornar a data atual em português (localmente):

```
<?
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo utf8_encode(strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today')));
//domingo, 22 de outubro de 2017
?>
```

Entretanto na produção está retornando, alterando essa linha, pois caso contrário não carrega, então removi o utf8_encode:

```
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));

Sunday, 22 de October de 2017
```

O sistema operacional do servidor está `America/Sao_Paulo`

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1):

Realmente o erro se dá no sistema operacional:

Resolvi, mudando a linguagem com o seguinte comando no `promt` do debian:

`export LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8`

Fica a dica, já tinha tentado de diversas formas.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de resolver o problema também é utilização de uma classe que traduz a string `Mes`.

Crie um array da data com a função `explode` nativa do php.

```
$data = explode('/', date('d/m/Y'));
```

e depois pegue este array e imprima o mês corrente.

> função

```
function Mes($nomemes, $formato = 'extenso'){
$formatoValido = array('extenso', 'abreviado');

if(!in_array($formato, $formatoValido)){
    return "Formato de data invalido";
}

$mes = array(
1 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Jan',
    'extenso'   => 'Janeiro'
    ),
2 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Fev',
    'extenso'   => 'Fevereiro'
    ),
3 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Mar',
    'extenso'   => 'Março'
    ),
4 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Abr',
    'extenso'   => 'Abril'
    ),
5 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Mai',
    'extenso'   => 'Maio'
    ),
6 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Jun',
    'extenso'   => 'Junho'
    ),
7 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Jul',
    'extenso'   => 'Julho'
    ),
8 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Ago',
    'extenso'   => 'Agosto'
    ),
9 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Set',
    'extenso'   => 'Setembro'
    ),
10 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Out',
    'extenso'   => 'Outubro'
    ),
11 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Nov',
    'extenso'   => 'Novembro'
    ),
12 => array(
    'abreviado' => 'Dez',
    'extenso'   => 'Dezembro'
    )
);
return $mes[$nomemes][$formato];
}
```

Nesta função criei duas formas de chamar a mesma com string por extenso e abreviada da seguinte forma

```
echo "São Paulo, ".$data[0]." de ".Mes($data[1])." de ".$data[2];//string no extenso São Paulo, 22 de Outubro de 2017
```

E valor abreviado

```
echo "São Paulo, ".$data[0]." de ".Mes($data[1],'abreviado')." de ".$data[2];// abreviado para São Paulo, 22 de Out de 2017
```